# Modeling binary star using MESA

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, binary-star

I'm trying to model a binary star using the MESA ([Modules for Experiments in Stellar Astrophysics docs](https://docs.mesastar.org/en/latest/)) code with an orbital period of 10 days with the scenario where mass transfers starts after the main sequence. Could someone provide a set of steps on how to go about this? My models diverge pretty early.

Answer (score 1):

The question is lacking somewhat in details. What have you tried? Did some options work better than others? What do you mean by models diverging rapidly?

The first place to start a new problem with MESA is to look at the test suite (in this case in the binary folder) for a starting set of inlists. You should also look at published sets of inlists to see if anything is similar to what you are doing. You can find available inlists either on [mesastar](https://cococubed.com/mesa_market/inlists.html) or on [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/communities/mesa/?page=1&size=20).